# IllegalStateException in oncreate Application class

Tags: java, android

I got an error java.lang.RuntimeException Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException in super.onCreate() in android version 8.0

```
public final class ClockApp extends Application {
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
  }
}
```

error log is given below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6065)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1764)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6942)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1538)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1484)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:663)
  at com.alarm.speakingclock.ClockApp.onCreate (ClockApp.java:14)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1126)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6062)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1764)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6942)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java) 
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: remove final keyword

Comment: according to the logcat, you are not only calling `super.onCreate()`, but also do `startService()`.

Comment: use workmanager or jobscheduler. you are getting this exceptionbecause of restrictions in latest os versions since you cannot start service when app is in background

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I have updated the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from API 26 you can't start a service when the app is not in foreground, and during `Application.onCreate()` call **it is still not in foreground**.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#StartingAService

So there are some possible ways to workaround this:

- *(Good solution)* Delay the service start until the app comes to foreground. For example - to the launcher activity's `onCreate` method.
- *(Good solution)* use `startForegroundService()`
- *(not sure if will work, bad solution)* downgrade targetSDK below 26